# Fetch API: invalid characters at the start of the string

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am trying to pull in data using the fetch API and ReadableStream and create a `CSV` file with the data.

However, the start of the string after decode always seems to have some invalid characters at the start.

Because of this, i am  unable to convert the text to csv properly.

I have tried `utf-8` and `utf-16le` encoding but still see the issue. Not sure what these characters mean. Below is my code

```
      const stream = await fetch(url);
      let reader = stream.body.getReader();
      //let chunks = [];
      let receivedLength = 0;
      while(true) {
        const {done, value} = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
          break;
        }
        receivedLength += value.length;
        await window.writeToStream(new TextDecoder("utf-16le").decode(value), false);
```

This results in something like in the file.

```
��Date  Column1 County  State   District
```

Any help on how to fix this would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that it's a BOM header, but to be sure.. download the file and share the first couple of bytes using `hexdump -C [file]`

Comment: I guess you confirmed it and open another question. Maybe you can close this one?

Comment: Hi @Evert, thanks for your comment. `00000000  44 61 74 65 09 53 65 6c  65 63 74 6f 72 54 6f 74` here is the first row of the output of your command. When i am setting the encoding to utf-16le i see garbage characters at the end of the output, but when i set encoding to utf-8, I see two BOM charcaters at the start. Any help on how i can avoid getting BOM character and just get the text would be really helpful, Thanks

Comment: HI @Evert. The issue was that the decoder i was using should have been outside the while loop for it to stream data correctly, the encoding i was supposed to use was `utf-16le`. the reason there were garbage characters at the end was because the stream propertly to the decode method was ignored, since it was inside while loop. Thanks.